# How can I send clients IP address with data from server to another client?

Tags: c#, sockets, server, tcp, client

I have developed a program which works like *client-server-client* model.

**I have achieved everything** and successfully have a **running code** for me to:

- send information from one client to another with multiple clients connected to the server
- Server acts as a man-in-the-middle and
- clients interact with each other

I want to know an efficient way to transfer clients(sender) ip address through server to client(receiver) with data(images, audio, etc) so that the receiving client can know who sent the specific data.

FYI there will be multiple clients who will continuously send data to a specific client at the same time so I need to distinguish between the sender of the data and have a record of which client sent specific data.

MY Code:

**Server:**

```
try
   {
    // receive data
    byte[] buffer = new byte[300000];
    current.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

    Console.WriteLine("Received: " + current.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None));
    ImageConverter convertData = new ImageConverter();
    Image image = (Image)convertData.ConvertFrom(buffer);
    image.Save("image.png");
    Console.WriteLine("Image saved");
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Image not saved");
         logFileWrite("Image not saved");
         Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Client:

```
try
{
    //send the file
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bm.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();

    ClientLiveScreenSocket.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    Console.WriteLine("Send success " + buffer.Length + " kb");
    logFileWrite("Send success " + buffer.Length + " kb");
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand if you already can _"send information from one client to another with **multiple clients connected to the server**"_ how come you can't _"I want to know...way to transfer clients(sender) ip address through server to client"_

Comment: _"efficient way"_ might be _subject to opinion_ and if so is sadly off-topic for SO. [ask].  Consider re-phrasing your question to be [constructive subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Deleted I can transfer the file in bytes from client to server to client but the receiving client will get the data from servers IP and not the sending clients IP. I want a way to get sending clients IP to receiving client.

Comment: You need to develop a protocol from you communication language.  When sending data you must be able to determine the start and end of every message.  So for text you usually terminate a message with a character than is not part of the message.  for binary or text you can add a byte count to beginning of the message and than have receiver read until all the bytes are received.

Comment: Create an OSI 7 protocol

Comment: Btw, your server code is invalid - calling to socket.Recieve second time just for logging, completely unacceptable. As for custom binary protocol - just send address bytes before or after image sending.

Comment: @karanugale _"`I have designed a protocol to send ipaddress` and image data in byte[] over socket and receive it on the other end..."_ - I thought that was the essence of your **question**?  _"but how can I send the length with it?"_ - this is suspicious considering what you have claimed you can do.  Clearly a sign of _moving the goal post_.

Answer (score 0):

After (or before) image having sent, send `IPAddress`'s wired representation:

```
var wireFormat = sourceClientAddress.GetAddressBytes();

current.Send(wireFormat, 0, wireFormat.Length, SocketFlags.None);
```

On client side you just receive these 4(16) bytes and reconstruct that address via:

```
// pseudo code
byte[] clientBytes = GetAccordingToMyProtocol();

//real code
var sourceClientAddress = new IPAddress(clientBytes);
```

So, any sequence of `socket.Receive` and `socket.Send` calls (both on client side and server side) according to your application logic is called application *protocol*. Often these entities become separate programming abstractions in big codebases.

**UPDATE**

Check [this](https://github.com/VinnieThePooh/playing.networking) repo.
There is a lot of space to refactoring and there is a bug - image is not passed, but it is matter of time to fix it.

So, there are 3(4) projects in ImageRetranslation folder, run them in turn (i mainly ran them in debug mode, there can be bugs without debugger exactly, i know):

1. Retranslation server
2. Retranslation receiver
3. And just once (without debug) - ImageSourceClient - actually sends image to server.

So, despite of bug with image transferring the feature you requested for - passing host:port works well.

See ya!

**UPDATE 2**

Bugs fixed, repo is viable - check it out.

Comment: Is there anyway I can send my data like "ipaddress of client and image data" so that receiving end can read it as "Ipaddress: Image"?

Comment: Use length-prefixed approach: server sends length of image (in bytes), client reads strictly those number of bytes (and saves image). Then read what is left - it would be ipaddress. Or you can receive ipaddress first, then image data second - it's up to you to design your own *protocol*.

Comment: Need code sample?

Comment: Yes, I think sample would help because I have been dealing with educating myself over byte[] for 1 week and so far I have achieved this. I have designed a protocol to send ipaddress and image data in byte[] over socket and receive it on the other end but how can I send the length with it? if I send length in the first byte then for the client to read that first byte it must have every byte in the byte[] first and that doesn't makes any sense.

Comment: Sorry if I'm over explaining this but I'm really eager to learn about socket programming.

Comment: Ok, i will update answer later.

Comment: @karanugale _"I have designed a protocol `to send ipaddress`"_ - I thought that was the essence of your **question**?  _"but how can I send the length with it?"_ - this is suspicious considering what you have claimed you can do.  Clearly a sign of _moving the goal post_.

Comment: @karanugale _"but how can I send the length with it?"_ - please take note of _["Looks like <refer to original problem> is solved isn't it? As for <refer to "next" problem>, that would be a different question, consider posting it separately."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253829/585968)_

Comment: no the protocol is designed but not implemented as I have doubt creating it and that is the purpose for this question. I have abit knowledge of byte[] but not everything that is needed. I just need a process to send length first and read ipaddress and image as same data.